# Computer Sleep Shortcut Issue

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, sleep, hibernate

I have gone through many forum and reference pages about the creation of a sleep shortcut on a computer without a designated sleep button. I see that to create a working sleep shortcut, you have to disable hibernate.  I am intent on using both, if possible.

I am using a shortcut to a file that runs the command on Windows 10:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

When hibernate is enabled, the command will put the computer into hibernate, not sleep.  I am looking to have my power button put the computer into hibernate, and have the hot-key put the computer into sleep mode.

Is there any possible way to create a hot-key shortcut to sleep on Windows 10 while also having hibernate enabled? And is there any way to prevent the computer from asking me about letting the file make changes every time I run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there any possible way to create a hot-key shortcut to sleep on Windows 10

Download [`psshutdown`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals).

Have the shortcut run the following batch file:

```
@echo off
psshutdown -d
exit
```

- `-d` Suspend the computer.

---

#### psshutdown

> You can use PsShutdown to initiate a shutdown of the local or a remote computer, logoff a user, lock a system, or to abort an imminent shutdown.

```
Usage: psshutdown [[\\computer[,computer[,..] | @file [-u user [-p psswd]]] -s|-r|-h|-d|-k|-a|-l|-o [-f] [-c] [-t nn|h:m] [-n s] [-v nn] [-e [u|p]:xx:yy] [-m "message"]
-   Displays the supported options.
computer    Perform the command on the remote computer or computers specified. If you omit the computer name the command runs on the local system, and if you specify a wildcard (\\*), the command runs on all computers in the current domain.
@file   Run the command on each computer listed in the text file specified.
-u  Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
-p  Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
-a  Aborts a shutdown (only possible while a countdown is in progress).
-c  Allows the shutdown to be aborted by the interactive user.
-d  Suspend the computer.
-e  Shutdown reason code.
Specify 'u' for user reason codes and 'p' for planned shutdown reason codes.
xx is the major reason code (must be less than 256).
yy is the minor reason code (must be less than 65536).
-f  Forces all running applications to exit during the shutdown instead of giving them a chance to gracefully save their data.
-h  Hibernate the computer.
-k  Poweroff the computer (reboot if poweroff is not supported).
-l  Lock the computer.
-m  This option lets you specify a message to display to logged-on users when a shutdown countdown commences.
-n  Specifies timeout in seconds connecting to remote computers.
-o  Logoff the console user.
-r  Reboot after shutdown.
-s  Shutdown without power off.
-t  Specifies the countdown in seconds until the shutdown (default: 20 seconds) or the time of shutdown (in 24 hour notation).
-v  Display message for the specified number of seconds before the shutdown. If you omit this parameter the shutdown notification dialog displays and specifying a value of 0 results in no dialog.
```

Source [`psshutdown`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: Is there a way to make the psshutdown window close?  When I open my computer again, there is a terminal window that was opened when psshutdown was initiated.

Comment: Add `exit` as the last line of the batch file. Answer updated.